# Centered graphic shifts too much to the left on resize

Tags: css, html

Hi could someone help with a problem I have.

Basically it's just a landing page with a photo that covers the whole background.

Next I have a graphic that depicts some text which I want centered vertically and horizontally using absolute positioning.

I've managed to do that and get it okay in terms of it's position when the viewport is 1200px wide however if you resize your browser the background and then the text graphic resizes accordingly but the text graphic shifts too much to the left.  I would like it to still shrink when resizing the browser but to retain it's horizontally centered position as much as possible.

You can see it here

www.juanchandler.com/test/

the css is all the head of the document so you can view source.

Could someone please advise me on how I can correct this.

Comment: Please create a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net).

Answer (score 0):

Not the best job with the centering... Try this for the small image:

```
.the-text {
    margin: auto;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

Of course, remove the previous margins.

Comment: Hi thanks alot just for the previous person the fiddle is here http://jsfiddle.net/juan808/e6qu6/

Comment: Thanks alot I tried it myself and it works. I do appreciate that...thanks again!

Comment: You're welcome! Now don't forget you need to mark questions as answered if there's an answer that helped you. I see you never selected an answer for any of the questions you asked - if you continue like that, there are chances that people here on SO won't bother much with your next questions.